# Are Hashed Timelock Contracts and Zero-Knowledge Contingent Payments the same thing?

Tags: cryptography, locktime, zero-knowledge

This answer to [How is a node in the middle prohibited from keeping the money in a routed Payment in Lightning network?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/43190/5406) describes how a Hashed Timelock Contract would be used to exchange the "secret" for a payment. This sounds a lot like the [Zero-Knowledge Contingent Payment](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1378318.0) described by Greg Maxwell.

Would I be correct in assuming that the HTLC would be implemented including a ZKCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Both use OP_CLTV, in order to recover from a situation where one side refuses to participate in the protocol, but other than that, they're pretty different.

[ZKCP](https://bitcoincore.org/en/2016/02/26/zero-knowledge-contingent-payments-announcement/) has a zero knowledge proof communicated outside of the blockchain. On the other hand, HTLC passes signed transactions back and forth to update a channel.